# Como impedir de bloqueio de popup ao retorno de ajax post?

Tags: javascript

Segue código:

**JS:**

```
function OnSuccess() {
    var url = "/Controller/VisualizarBoleto/" + 00;
    window.open(url, "WindowPopup", 'width=668,height=780');
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema não está exibindo popup, o navegador fica bloqueando.

Sei que dá para desbloquear usando a configuração do navegador.

Existe outra maneira sem ir na configuração do navegador ?

Porque um "novato" que não sabe o que está acontecendo com site.(popup bloqueado), ele nunca vai saber se está bloqueado. Por isso fiz uma pergunta de como impedir de bloqueio de popup.

Fiz um pequeno exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/WQXXT/5171/

Como posso evitar isso ?

Comment: Aqui tá funfando, tem de ver se seu navegador não está bloquenado o pop up em configurações

Comment: Pela configuração do navegador funciona, não existe maneira sem depender config do navegador ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parece que popup blockers tentam sempre barrar quando o popup **não é resultado de uma ação do usuário**.

> Uma possível solução é retirar a sua função `window.open` de dentro do `OnSuccess` e mover para um botão.

[Exemplo no jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/s69re3xL/1/)

Outra opção seria tentar usar um iframe, que pode sobrepor outros elementos na página, e não é bloqueado pelos browsers.

[Veja um exemplo usando iframe](https://jsfiddle.net/bu0agvmo/)

E acho que não dá para deixar de citar uma opção "pronta":

O [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) do [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).